# resize columns if kendo grid is bound to dynamic data source?

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I am trying to enable horizontal scrolling for my kendo grid. So far I've heard if you have added `width` to the columns definitions. But what do you do if data is dynamic?

I've tried a couple of things. This code can help you understand that.

```
 var kgrid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    height: 155,
    pageable: true,
    dataSource:ds,
    dataBound:function(e){
        var m = kgrid.data('kendoGrid');            
        console.log('dataBound: ', m.columns);
    },
    dataBinding:function(e){
        var m = kgrid.data('kendoGrid');
        var obj = ds.view()[0];
        console.log('dataBinding columns before: ', m.columns);
        //for(x in obj){
        //    if(x[0] == '_')
        //        continue;
        //    m.columns.push({field: x, width:'200px'});
        //}
        console.log('dataBinding columns after: ', m.columns);
    }//,
    //columns:[
      //  {field:'col1', width: '200px'},
        //{field:'col2', width: '200px'},
        //{field:'col3', width: '200px'},
        //{field:'col4', width: '200px'}
        //]
});
```

Also here is the link to my page: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/497zM/3/

I want to set some size to the column, and hence enable horizontal scrolling.

Comment: The columns seem to adjust themselves evenly if grid.width < parent.width. To enable horizontal scrolling you need to ensure the total width of all columns is greater than the container's width.

Comment: @lrb that figures...but at which stage in the binding lifecycle will I be able to find all columns my datadource returns, set column widths, and instruct the grid to use those columns?...the columns are dynamic.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. I would think that if the column widths make the grid stretch outside of the parent then having scrolling set to auto will cause the containing element to show scroll. If you have only one column then it will take 100 and or the width or whatever you have set for the width of that column. Maybe I am off here :(

Comment: @lrb I agree with you on the scrolling part. The fields my datasource returns are dynamic. Their numbers can either reduce or increase. The fiddle I put there mocks this scenario: I am accepting no.of rows & columns as input, then clicking on a button to generate data, passing that to the echo api to simulate an ajax request. Hence the `ds.read(...)` does this much. I do not specify any `columns` while grid initialization. The `dataBound` event has fired. Whatever I try in that event in order to resize the columns don't work...

Comment: Are you using Kendo's mvvc style type

Comment: Found an answer. But I still believe there must be a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see as of now you can do this is to completely destroy the grid and re-bind it every time new data arrives. And when it arrives we'd have to take the first item, read the properties and create the `columns` array. We'd have to set each object's `width` property here like mentioned below:

```
success: function (data) {
        var cols = [];
        var item = data[0];
        $.each(item, function (key, val) {
            cols.push({
                field: key,
                width: '325px'
            });
        });

        theGrid.kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: data,
                pageSize: 5
            },
            pageable: true,
            columns: cols,
            height: 225
        });
    } //end success
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/497zM/5/